# Autocapitalize/correct two connected words?

Tags: scrivener, capitalization

Let's say I have a character in my story simply called "Slime Monster". With every instance of these two words, I want both words to be capitalized and to be corrected as a pair, so if I mistype it to something like "Silme Mosnter" it will recognize the correct spelling as "Slime Monster".

Is there a way to set up the dictionary like that? I'm using the Windows version (Version 1.9.9.0).

Comment: Ahh, Mac and ios use the os for spellcheck (I know how to edit those). PC is different and uses Scrivener "dictionaries". Try a search for "Scrivener PC dictionary spellcheck".

Comment: Scrivener versions seem to be quite different. It would be a good idea to always mention the version of the software you are using and the operating system for future software related questions. That makes it a lot easier to search for relevant information.

Comment: I can't get the autocomplete feature to work with the beta version of Scrivener 3 (the beta is labeled as 2.X by the way, so you'll likely just skip that when you upgrade), but shouldn't it theoretically be enough to set up the autocomplete and get used to using it whenever you type the name of a monster / character / ...? I can't test this but the box for autocomplete entries lets me add multiple words for one entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches.

1. **Before you start typing your text.** You can set up a list of auto-complete words. From Project -> Project Settings -> autocomplete.
2. **After you typed.** You can use the find command in Edit -> Find. Set the Find Options to Regular Expressions (regex). Place the desired Regular expression in the top box, and Slime Monster in the lower box. Make sure you tick the ignore case box and you are good to go. *If you are worried that the regex will have false positives, you can click on Next and only replace those occurrences that look wrong.*

### A bit on Regex.

This requires some knowledge of what regex can do. The one fitting your request could be a search for the two words containing the letters of Slime and Monster.

```
\b[slime]+\b \b[monster]+\b
```

Note that this will also match any pair of words whose letters are included in slime and in monster, e.g. "me so" and "see soon"

A bit more complex regex, which is also more accurate, could be:

```
\b(?=\b(?:[^slime]*[slime]){4,6}[^slime]*\b)[slime]{4,6}\b \b(?=\b(?:[^monster]*[monster]){5,8}[^monster]*\b)[monster]{5,8}\b
```

[slime]{4,6} tries to match any word made from the letters in slime, with length between 4 and 6. The whole thing tries to match a pair of words, the first of which is between 4 and 6 letters and is composed only of letters from "slime", and the second is between 5 and 8 letters and is composed only of the letters found in "monster". Note that there is a space in between the two, which is also used in the matching.

As written above, do not forget to check the ignore case if you want to correct the capitalization as well.

This answer was inspired by the excellent SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order